# How to return a matrix from Web Service (Axis2-java)?

Tags: java, web-services, matrix, apache-axis, webservice-client

I'm trying send 2 matrix names to matrix multiplication function (matrisCarp) which in server but getting this error : ***The method setMatris2(Matris1Stub.ArrayOfint[]) in the type Matris1Stub.MatrisCarp is not applicable for the arguments (int[][])***

This is my server codes :

public class matris1 {

```
public String sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
     return a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b);
     }
public static int[][] matrisCarp(int[][] matris1, int[][] matris2 , int n){
    int i,j,k;
    int[][] yeniMatris= new int[n][n];
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<n; ++j)
        for(k=0; k<n; ++k)
        yeniMatris[i][k] += matris1[i][j] * matris2[j][k];
    return yeniMatris;

}
```

}

This is my client codes :

public class matrisClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int matrisdegeri=0;
       JFrame jfrm=new JFrame("Matris Programý");
       jfrm.setSize(1000,1000);

       jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       JLabel jlab=new JLabel("Matris boyutunu giriniz:");

       matrisdegeri =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(jlab));

       int[][] randomMatrix1= RandomArray(matrisdegeri);
       int[][] randomMatrix2= RandomArray(matrisdegeri);

       String sonuc="Birinci Matris:  "+Arrays.deepToString(randomMatrix1)+"  \n  "
            + "  Ýkinci Matris:  "+Arrays.deepToString(randomMatrix2);


       JLabel jlab2=new JLabel(sonuc);
       panel.add(jlab2);
       jfrm.add(panel);
       jfrm.setVisible(true);
       DosyayaEkle(sonuc);

       ***try{
           Matris1Stub stub = new Matris1Stub();
           MatrisCarp mc = new MatrisCarp();
           mc.setMatris1(randomMatrix1);
           mc.setMatris2(randomMatrix2);
           mc.setN(matrisdegeri);
           MatrisCarpResponse res = stub.matrisCarp(mc);
           System.out.println(res.get_return());
           }***

       catch(AxisFault e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       catch(RemoteException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


}

private static int[][] RandomArray(int n) {
    int[][] randomMatrix = new int [n][n];

    Random rand = new Random(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            Integer r = rand.nextInt(100)+1; 
            randomMatrix[i][j] = Math.abs(r);
        }

    }
return randomMatrix;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had problems in axis and axis 2 swnding lists of lists and such.

You don't need the matrix to be n-dimensional. Just send one big one-dimensional array and the dimensions after peopcessing. In your case ad width and heigth and send all the ints as a one big row in order.

Another way: bytearray them and encode in base64

Comment: I create an array and copied to my matrix values to this array . After that i send array to server . I'm converting my array to matrix again in server . Thanks for help .